# Meteor with Promises

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise, bluebird

I've been trying to get into the habit of using promises but ran into problems while trying to use them in server side code in the context of Meteor. This is the problem:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    p = function(){
      return new Promise(function(res,rej) {
        res("asd");
      });
    };
    p().then(function(asd){
      console.log("asd is " + asd);
      return "zxc"
    }).then(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(zxc){
      console.log("zxc is " + zxc);
      return "qwe"
    })).then(function(qwe){
      console.log("qwe is " + qwe);
    });
  });
}
```

`mvrx:bluebird` package is installed

code also available at [GitHub](https://github.com/RobertBorg/meteor-bluebird-test)

Expected output:

```
asd is asd         
zxc is zxc
qwe is qwe
```

Actual output:

```
asd is asd         
zxc is zxc
qwe is undefined
```

Dropping the `Meteor.bindEnvironment` wrapper fixes the problem, but i need it in order to be able to use Collections inside the callbacks

So what am i missing here? is it just not possible to use Promises + Meteor this way or is there a bug?

What i'm actually trying to accomplish is parallel pipelines that have important partial results but need a synchronized ending. Something like this.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup


    promises = [];

     step1 = function(input){
        return new Promise(function(res, rej){
          console.log(input + ":Step 1");
          res(input);
        });
      };
      step2 = function(input){
        return new Promise(function(res, rej){
          console.log(input + ":Step 2");
          res(input);
        });
      };
      step3 = function(input){
        return new Promise(function(res, rej){
          console.log(input + ":Step 3");
          res(input);
        });
      };
      slowIO = function(input){
        var inp = input;
        return new Promise( function(res,rej){
          setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(inp + ":SlowIO");
            res(inp);
          },Math.random()*20000);
        });
      };
      end = function(input){
        return new Promise(function(res,rej){
          console.log(input + ": done, commiting to database");
          res()
        });
      };

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      promises.push(step1("pipeline-" + i).then(step2).then(slowIO).then(step3).then(end));
    };

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
      console.log("All complete")
    });



  });
}
```

Comment: You can promisify bindEnvironment with `Promise.promisify` since it's an errback, check the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Update: [I've logged an issue on github to see if it can be resolved.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/4420))

Looks like there's a issue with `Meteor.bindEnvironment` when used this way.

[If it's called from outside a `Fiber` it won't return it's value.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/556c0e28e94b9351cbf0b28e80a71a4e35f1362a/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js#L122) *Notice the missing `return` before `Fiber(runWithEnvironment).run()`*

A simple solution for the moment is to return a Promise instead of the result:

```
// when passed as a callback to `Promise#then`
//  allows it to resolve asynchronously
var asyncThen = function(fn){
  return function(arg){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      fn(arg, resolve, reject);
    })
  };
};

Promise.resolve("asd").then(function(asd){
  console.log("asd is " + asd);
  return "zxc"
}).then(
  asyncThen(
    Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(zxc, resolve, reject){
      console.log("zxc is", zxc);
      resolve("qwe");
    })
  )
).then(function(qwe){
  console.log("qwe is " + qwe);
});
```

Comment: Looks like not returning the value is by design: see `packages/meteor.js:1003` I also tried patching it by simply putting an return there which causes errors while compiling. Doing it the way you propose doesn't work for me since i'm already outside the fiber when calling bindEnvironment and therefore i get the "Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. ..." error when trying to bind it.

Comment: Hmm.. appears so; I've updated my answer to something workable

Comment: In `workFn` you mean to use zxc and not argZxc right? cause that works.

Comment: @RauBan I've tweaked it again to something a bit cleaner / re-usable

Comment: Thanks, that's really neat. I added `var fn = Meteor.bindEnvironment(fn);` to further reduce the clutter while chaining.

Answer (score 1):

A promise is just a way to write async code in a synchronous fashion.
If that's all your after, why not use `Meteor.wrapAsync()`? In your case, you've got `zxc` riding cowboy in it's own fiber & who knows when it's coming back. Bluebird is great & super fast on the client, but I think the code is much cleaner using what Meteor gives you:

```
//*UNTESTED*//
asd = function() { return 'foo';};
asdSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(asd);
asdResult = asdSync();

qwe = function(input) {return input.reverse()};
qweSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(qwe);
qweResult = qweSync(asdResult); //should return 'oof'
```