# Promises and Meteor.call()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a `Meteor.method()` that server side returns a promise from `oracledb`. Client side I have:

```
Meteor.call('myMethod', (error, result) => {
  result.then() // err -> no .then() method?, 
});
```

So what is `result`? It does not have a `.then()` method, so it is not a promise?

Comment: Check on that post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358232/meteor-with-promises

Comment: So there is a better solution than using the above suggested `Meteor.bindEnvironment` and `Meteor.waitAsync` according to this https://blog.meteor.com/using-promises-on-the-client-in-meteor-fb4f1c155f84

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meteor does not "send" the promise to the client.

The server returns a result value to the client (which triggers the callback) once the promise is resolved (or rejected) on the server, and not at the moment the promise is returned from the method itself (unless it is already settled when returned).

You can also use async/await to simplify the code.

Here is [a blog post](https://blog.meteor.com/using-promises-and-async-await-in-meteor-8f6f4a04f998) with more details about the using asynchronous code in methods.

**Note:**

The value sent from the server is serialized using EJSON. Object methods, getters, etc. are stripped from it, unless you create a [custom serializer](https://docs.meteor.com/api/ejson.html#EJSON-addType). In some cases, serialization might even fail (I think it happened with certain `moment` objects) and result in `undefined` being returned.

Comment: So I think the value is returned before the promise is resolved, hence the `result` is missing it's getter methods?

Comment: You cannot return a non-serializable object from a Meteor method. It has to be EJSON-serializable and therefore, unless you have a custom serializer, you cannot have an object with getters. If you want, you can share more specific code and I will try to explain what's going on.

Comment: Ah, this could be the explanation. While debugging in Chrome I was wondering why the attributes of the object were populated with expected values, but the getter methods returned `undefined`. Now, in Chrome dev tools eclipses (...) were displayed next to the getter methods and if you click these the expected value was evaluated - hence I was thinking this was an async issue.

Comment: AAAArrgggh! This has been my problem all along, why why why will Meteor not warn me when serializing unserializable objects!!!

Comment: If you enter that comment with EJSON as an answer, I will score it as the correct answer. Problem is solved now.

Comment: I added a note.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor is not using promises by default, however, you can wrap your Meteor.calls into a promise function as below

```
const callWithPromise = (method, myParameters) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Meteor.call(method, myParameters, (err, res) => {
      if (err) reject('Something went wrong');
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}

(async function() {
  const myValue1 = await callWithPromise('myMethod1', someParameters);
  const myValue2 = await callWithPromise('myMethod2', myValue1);
})();
```

Sample code has copied from [Meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/execute-code-once-the-meteor-callback-has-run/25905/4).

Also, [this topic](https://forums.meteor.com/t/start-using-async-await-instead-of-promises-and-callbacks/17037/3) gives you a better insight in taking advantages of Aysnc/Await syntax or Promises in Meteor calls.